# _write et al. pulled in when linking C++ lib with bare-metal ARM C project

Tags: c++, c, linker, arm, cross-compiling

I've cross-compiled (for ARM Cortex-M4) an external C++ library/relinkable object file from source with the following flags:

```
  -fno-unwind-tables
  -ffunction-sections
  -fdata-sections
  -fmessage-length=0
  -std=c++11
  -fno-rtti
  -fno-exceptions
  -fno-threadsafe-statics
  -Wnon-virtual-dtor
  -fno-unwind-tables
  -ffreestanding
  -fno-non-call-exceptions
  -fno-use-cxa-atexit
  -fno-common
  -r
```

I've used the same flags to with `-C` to cross-compile a wrapper file that uses some of the library routines and exports a single `extern "C"` wrapped function. I then link the resulting object file with the aforementioned library by also passing additional flags:

```
-static -r -nostartfiles -nolibc -nodefaultlibs -nostdlib
```

I have a separate bare-metal C project in which I know call the exported C wrapper function and link it with the resulting library.

Doing this linking fails due to the following undefined references:

```
../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard/libc.a(lib_a-abort.o): in function `abort':
abort.c:(.text.abort+0xa): undefined reference to `_exit'

../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard/libc.a(lib_a-signalr.o): in function `_kill_r':
signalr.c:(.text._kill_r+0x12): undefined reference to `_kill'

../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard/libc.a(lib_a-signalr.o): in function `_getpid_r':
signalr.c:(.text._getpid_r+0x0): undefined reference to `_getpid'

../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard/libc.a(lib_a-writer.o): in function `_write_r':
writer.c:(.text._write_r+0x14): undefined reference to `_write'

../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard/libc.a(lib_a-closer.o): in function `_close_r':
closer.c:(.text._close_r+0xc): undefined reference to `_close'

../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard/libc.a(lib_a-fstatr.o): in function `_fstat_r':
fstatr.c:(.text._fstat_r+0x12): undefined reference to `_fstat'

../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard/libc.a(lib_a-isattyr.o): in function `_isatty_r':
isattyr.c:(.text._isatty_r+0xc): undefined reference to `_isatty'

../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard/libc.a(lib_a-lseekr.o): in function `_lseek_r':
lseekr.c:(.text._lseek_r+0x14): undefined reference to `_lseek'

../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard/libc.a(lib_a-readr.o): in function `_read_r':
readr.c:(.text._read_r+0x14): undefined reference to `_read'
```

I'm able to resolve this by either passing `--specs=nosys.specs` or simply `-lnosys` to the linker.

Here's what's confusing me: looking at the produced ELF with either `objdump --disassemble`, `strings` or `readelf -Ws` I can see the offending references. However, if I look at the artifact of the original C project or any of the C++ artifacts I bundle together and link to the project I don't see any of these symbols.

My conclusion was thus that they must get pulled in by the virtue of linking in the C++ library, although I don't understand why and I don't want to blindly rely on `nosyslib` just to run into some hard-to-reason-about bugs later down the road.

Comment: Note that although the C++ specifications define the requirements on freestanding C++ implementations, many of the supposed freestanding C++ implementations are problematic or non-conforming.  That includes g++ in freestanding mode, up to at least version 12.  MSVC and Clang don't even provide a freestanding mode for C++.

Comment: all those flags are not going to prevent you from linking something you have linked and that something is making system calls and you have not provided a system.  you need to not link or make those calls or you need to provide a system.

Comment: A C++ library is going to have system calls yes?  many.  If you want to use that library you will need a system.

Comment: Just FYI, you've got a duplicate `-fno-unwind-tables`.

Comment: @old_timer, although I suspect that the OP's "external" library indeed does have dependencies on the functions in question, that's not certain.  If it is designed to be usable in a freestanding implementation then it will not.  And if it does have such dependencies then it is unlikely to work as intended when those functions are stubbed out via nosyslib, but that's not certain, especially if the OP is using only a subset of the library's features.

Comment: My point is that these command line options do not remove any items that you have linked into your project.   And those unresolved externals are clearly system calls from a library.  Problem with not wanting a system means you cant have a language library like C or C++ because they are packed with system calls that you have to resolve.  No command line option is going to fix that

Comment: I can't argue with that, @old_timer.  In fact, I already said much the same in my answer.

Comment: that is not what the freestanding command line option does.  it prevents the tool from generating calls in the output, it does not prevent you from linking stuff that has calls you dont want.

Comment: C++ libraries are packed with system calls and good luck finding one that doesnt, in order to not it would have to make assumptions about your project that only you can make.  Instead you take on a library that is not as painful to resolve the calls.  Understand what calls you are making and what their side effects are and if you can simply stub out all of those calls to get it to build.  or if you have to resolve some of them to keep the library working.

Comment: Or the simple answer is if you do not want a system then you cannot have a C++ library, that is the easy solution.

Comment: Rather than rely on objdump, get the linker to output a map file directly.  That is likely to provide the information you need to trace back up the call graph to find where these are referenced.  `-Wl,-Map=output.map --cref`

Comment: As it turns out, I didn't use the same defines when compiling the wrapper file (which includes some of the same headers the external lib is built with). I'm a bit embarrassed to admit this is the second time this happened, only that first time it was more obvious due to a compilation, rather than a linking error. Anyway, I appreciate all you comments and the answer, I truly learned a lot today!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My conclusion was thus that they must get pulled in by the virtue of linking in the C++ library, although I don't understand why

Possibly because your version of g++ or of the c++ standard library is buggy with respect to freestanding mode.

Possibly because the library you are building `include`s one or more headers that are not on the allowed list for a freestanding implementation in the version of C++ you're compiling for.  Or maybe it genuinely relies on the functions in question.  In particular, if that library was not explicitly designed to be usable in conjunction with freestanding implementations, then it would be insanely lucky to find a combination of compile and link options that made it work correctly in a freestanding implementation.  Note well that "compiles and links successfully" is only a small part of "works as intended".

Possibly some other issue.

> and I don't want to blindly rely on nosyslib just to run into some hard-to-reason-about bugs later down the road.

nosyslib provides stub versions of various system calls, which always fail without doing anything (else).  This could be a source of bugs if the program does not properly check for and handle errors from syscalls, and / or if it in fact needs some of those syscalls to succeed in order to perform its intended work.

If those unresolved references are some kind of bogus artifact produced by your toolchain, meaning that no calls to those functions can ever actually be performed (see above comments about components being designed for freestanding mode), then nosyslib is probably a sturdy resolution.  If the stub functions actually do get called then you're on much shakier ground.  It may be hard to discern between these without a thorough review of *all* the code., including that of the "external" library.